# Race conditions in shell command lists

Tags: security, bash, shell, symlink, race-condition

How safe are command lists in shell (or bash) from race conditions?

```
if [ -h "$dir" ]; then
  echo 'Directory exists and is a symlink'
  exit 1
fi
cd "$dir"
```

The above code is obviously prone to race conditions: An attacker can create a symlink after the check, but still before changing the directory into it.

Does the same apply to `||` command lists? In other words: is the below command immune to race conditions, or do the same rules as above still apply?

```
[ -h "$dir" ] || cd "$dir"
```

With error message:

```
[ -h "$dir" ]
  && { echo 'Directory exists and is a symlink'; exit 1; }
  || cd "$dir"
```

Comment: Are you concerned that an attacker might _replace_ an existing directory with a symlink, or that s/he might _create_ a symlink, or both?

Comment: From the test manpage regarding -h: This operator is retained for compatibility with previous versions of this program. Do not rely on its existence; use -L instead.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Interesting… my manpage of sh(1) says exactly the opposite: »-L file       True if file exists and is a symbolic link.  This operator is retained for compatibility with previous versions of this program. Do not rely on its existence; use -h instead.« man bash(1) does not mention any difference between the two.

Comment: @AdamLiss: both. Anything he might do to trick me into a wrong directory. With creation a single racy if should suffice, but when he replaces an existing directory with a symlink after check but before changing to the directory, I might end up somewhere else.

Comment: @knittl http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/ The open group specification does not appear to indicate any difference between -h and -L.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only two secure and relatively portable ways to change directory without following a symbolic link.   Neither is easily possible in shell scripts.

Assume for the sake of discussion that we're trying to safely chdir into "foo".  The first way is to save the current directory in an open file descriptor with `open(".", O_RDONLY)`, `lstat()` the "foo" directory, record the `st_dev` and `st_ino` values that result, call chdir("foo") and then stat() ".".    Compare the resulting the `st_dev` and `st_ino` values.    If they are the same, you won the race.   If not, issue an error message, `fchdir()` back using your saved fd, and then either abort or try again.

The second, less portable way, is to use `fd = open("foo", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW)` and then `fchdir(fd)`.  You can also use `openat` instead of `open` here.   The portability problem is that not all systems have `O_NOFOLLOW` and some older kernels won't correctly interpret that flag (instead they ignore it, which is a security issue).

For more information take a look at the source code of GNU find, in which I go to quite some trouble to avoid this kind of problem, using a method very similar to the one described above.

As for solving this problem in a shell script:

If your system has a `stat(1)` command or something like Perl, you can use those to perform the stat operations; you can record the result in a shell variable.   This means you can more or less implement the first method in a shell script, except for the need to use `fchdir` to recover.   If it is OK to simply abort immediately when your shell script loses the race, you can certainly adapt the first method for use in the shell.   But in the end writing secure code in shell is very, very difficult.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I'm [already using `stat`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9549413/112968#comment-12103060) to compare inodes after changing into the directory

Answer (score 3):

This is a great educational question, but in practice you're solving the wrong problem.  Rather than worrying about scripting concurrency issues, the linux security model relies on file system permissions.

If you're worried that an attacker may change the working environment beneath an executing program, then you should protect the environment: ensure that only you have write access to the scripts and binaries that will be running, and create files and directories only in locations that only you can write to.

For binary executables, look into using the [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit, which allows an ordinary user to execute them with elevated privileges, but be warned that any process that runs in this fashion must be carefully debugged and checked for security issues.  Most linux distributions won't allow scripts to run in this manner, however.

It's worth mentioning that an attacker who's obtained your (or the root) password can easily defeat this and other security measures, but in that case you've got bigger problems.  :-)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The script in question is/will be run as setuid and gets passed a directory as its first argument, which it will `cd` into and then perform a number of `chmod`+`chown` tasks. (And I don't want someone to perform that tasks on files he is not allowed to)

Comment: You're better off using a different programming language, probably.

Comment: If instead there is something special about the chown commands, perhaps that all the changes are between a limited number of Unix users, and issued by a limited (possibly disjoint) set of users, then you can avoid having a setuid shell scripts, and instead change `chown` to `sudo chown` in the script.

Comment: @JamesYoungman: I don't see a difference between setuid and running a script through sudo. In the end, it's executed as root.

Comment: @knittl, yikes!  [You should never make a shell script setuid](http://profesores.elo.utfsm.cl/~agv/elo330/programs/shell/NotUseSetuidScripts.html).  That is [a major security hole](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html): there's [no reasonable way to make it secure](http://perl.plover.com/classes/unixsec/samples/slide013.html).  You need to use a language that is better-suited for this: probably C.

Comment: @D.W. thanks for those links. Although I could not reproduce the obvious bugs (linking to -i does not do anything (and there's a workaround), exporting IFS does not work either). Yes, I know, just because I'm not able to exploit it, does not mean that nobody else will be.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why using `||` would not be vulnerable to the same race condition.  Indeed, for it not to be vulnerable, it would need to be implemented using either

- some kind of atomic stat-and-chdir filesystem operation (which I'm pretty sure doesn't exist), or
- some kind of double check after the `cd` to ensure that the directory still points to the same place it used to.

I'm no bash guru, but I'm pretty sure neither of these is the case.

Comment: Double checking sounds like a good idea and is perhaps the only safe way.

Comment: I suspect that's the way to go, too. Do note, however, that it's not enough to check that the original directory path still resolves to the same place: someone could've changed it _twice_. Instead, you need to `stat` the directory you've actually changed to and check that it's the same directory you `stat`ed originally.

Comment: thanks for making sure I do it the right way. I'm already comparing inodes: `stat -c%i dir && cd dir && stat -c%i '.' && compare both inodes`. I don't know how I would even check if the path resolves to the same directory without introducing another race condition ;)

Comment: @D.W.: I'm only doing a single check.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can't avoid race conditions in shell scripts.  You'll need to use C, and use the TOCTTOU-safe interfaces, like `openat`, `fchdir`, and the like.  Avoiding TOCTTOU (race) vulnerabilities is non-trivial and requires careful study.